# Java: Check if a number is a double digit or single-digit no if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, numbers, digits

I have homework to check if number is a double digit or a single-digit without using if statement. Thanks for your help!

```
public class SchoolTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        x = reader.nextInt();
        if ((x > 9 && x < 100) || (x < -9 && x > -100)) {
            System.out.println(true);
            main(args);
        } else {
            System.out.println(false);
            main(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use an if statement?

Comment: My teacher told us to think how to not use the if statement

Comment: It's good practice to explain your code a bit when you post a question. :)

Answer (score 12):

Just set the value to the conditional:

```
boolean isDoubleDigit = (x > 9 && x < 100) || (x < -9 && x > -100);
System.out.println( isDoubleDigit );
```

Answer (score 3):

If the number is known to be non-negative:

```
int digits = Integer.toString(theIntValue).trim().length();
```

(`trim()` probably isn't needed.)

If it might be negative:

```
int digits = Integer.toString(Math.abs(theIntValue)).trim().length();
```

If you must return a boolean:

```
boolean isTwoDigit = Integer.toString(Math.abs(theIntValue)).trim().length() == 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Digits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int check = scan.nextInt();
        //False for single digit, true for double digit
        boolean isDoubleDigit = (check / 10 == 0 && check / 100 == 0) ? false : true;
        System.out.println(isDoubleDigit);
    }
}
```

Ternary operator is quite helpful in your case

Comment: Don't really need the ternary operator either, `bool isDoubleDigit = ! ( check / 10 == 0 && check / 100 == 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

You could read the number in as a String rather than an int and use Regex

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: It might be over kill, clcto has a simpler answer.

This tutorial might help:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html

Answer (score -2):

Should have been written without the main (args)

Comment: Put differently; this is not an answer, and is vague and more likely to lead the asker (and anyone who sees this) off-track rather than actually help.